# The training sequences are of feature dimension 60093 but the input layer expects sequences of feature dimension 39

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, lstm, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement LSTM on speech emotion recognition, I have a training matrix 60093 by 39 and test matrix 76503 by 39 with a separate label matrix of each of them, when I executed the code below I got this error `The training sequences are of feature dimension 60093 but the input layer expects sequences of feature dimension 39`

```matlab
% Load the dataset
load('C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\deep_learning_matrix\matrice_mfcc_app.mat');
load('C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\deep_learning_matrix\matrice_mfcc_test.mat');

num_classes = 7;


% Transpose the training and test matrices
mfcc_matrix_app = mfcc_matrix_app';  % Transpose the training matrix
mfcc_matrix_test = mfcc_matrix_test';  % Transpose the test matrix

%featureSequences = HelperFeatureVector2Sequence(mfcc_matrix_app,20,5);
% Update the num_features variable with the correct value
num_features = size(mfcc_matrix_app, 2);
% Define the LSTM network architecture
num_hidden_units = 64;
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(num_features)
    lstmLayer(num_hidden_units, 'OutputMode', 'last')
    fullyConnectedLayer(num_classes)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer];


% Specify the training options
max_epochs = 20;
mini_batch_size = 128;
initial_learning_rate = 0.001;

options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs', max_epochs, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', mini_batch_size, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', initial_learning_rate, ...
    'GradientThreshold', 1, ...
    'Shuffle', 'every-epoch', ...
    'Verbose', 1, ...
    'Plots', 'training-progress');
`
% Train the LSTM network
net = trainNetwork(mfcc_matrix_app, CA, layers, options);

% Evaluate the performance of the trained model on the test data
predicted_labels = classify(net, mfcc_matrix_test);
accuracy = sum(predicted_labels == CT) / 7;
confusion_matrix = confusionmat(CT, predicted_labels);
disp(['Accuracy: ' num2str(accuracy)]);
disp('Confusion Matrix:');
disp(confusion_matrix);
```

This is my workspace

[image]

Comment: The error suggests you simply made a transposing error somewhere, causing the large dimension to be seen as features, instead of observations.

Comment: I have done the trnsposing, still seen the issue